# Converting nmake to make

Tags: unix, makefile, porting, nmake

Is there a tool in the market that takes Visual Studio "nmake" files, and converts them to Unix-style "make" files? Is there any tool that eases the pain of managing makefiles in large projects?

Comment: have you seen this http://www.mail-archive.com/help-make@gnu.org/msg05924.html ?

Comment: currently im trying https://github.com/Footsiefat/NMake2MSBuild

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't seen any tools which automatically can convert nmake to unix make, but there are several tools to aid in managing makefiles in large projects. My favorite one is [CMake](http://www.cmake.org).

Answer (score 0):

I think the frustrations you're experiencing have been addressed by the industry via the [Ant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant) and Ant-related technologies.  ([NAnt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAnt))

Ant is:

- cross-platform
- not tied to OS shell commands
- no more whitespace issues

Alternatively, since you mentioned you're using VisualStudio, you might consider migrating to Microsoft's [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wea2sca5(VS.80).aspx) -- Microsoft's (relatively new) build engine for VisualStudio.